# how to separate the multiple inputs using space in console

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to get the subject name and marks from the console.  I am using the split() to separate the subject and marks. for example subject name and mark **English 90**. I am using space to split the subject and marks. Main problem is when i get the subject name like **computer science 90** the split() is not working. How can i separate the inputs??

```
string name1 = Console.ReadLine();
string sub = name1.Split(' ')[0];
string mark = name1.Split(' ')[1];
total += Convert.ToInt32(mark);
Console.Write(sub + " " + mark + "  ");
```

Comment: Spliting 'computer science 90 ' gets 'cumputer', 'science' and '90'. So you tatal calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use LINQ for this purpose by helping [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Last`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.100).aspx) methods:

```
string name1 = Console.ReadLine();
var temp = name1.Split(' ');
string sub = string.Join(" ", temp.TakeWhile(c => c != temp.Last()));
string mark = temp.Last();
total += Convert.ToInt32(mark);
Console.Write(sub + " " + mark + "  ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can locate the last space index using [LastIndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) and then apply [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) the text before and after.

```
int lastSpaceIndex = line.LastIndexOf(" ");
string subject = line.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
string grade = line.Substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1);
```

Comment: i am going to give the inputs in run time only. Inputs may be like English 90 (or) Computer science 85. Then how can i  mention the index number if i entered English 90 my index 0 will be English and Index 1 will be 90. But in the Computer Science 85 my index 0 will be Computer and index 1 will be Science then how can i change it in run time???

Comment: I also didn't mention the Index, it was automatically located by `line` variable, or in your example `name1` (instead of line).

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Split. You can provide the character(s) that you want to use to split the string into multiple. If you provide none all white-spaces are assumed as split-characters

```
string[] tokens = line.Split();
```

or, if you want to use only spaces as delimiter:

```
string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');
```

If you want to parse them to int you can use `Array.ConvertAll():`

```
int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(tokens, int.Parse);
```

If you want to check if the format is valid use int.TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 2 inputs instead for example:

```
   string sub = Console.ReadLine();
   string mark = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.Write(sub + " " + mark + " ");
```